# IOS - close UIViewContoller from current UIViewController without navigation controller (storyboard)

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, dismiss

In this case:
I have 4 `UIViewController` called A,B,C,D, and E.
Steps:

1. Display modal B view controller from A
2. Display modal C view controller from B
3. Display modal D view controller from C
4. Display modal E view controller from D

   Finally, close B, C and D view controller from current view controller which is D. Also, when I call `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]` in D view controller, back to A view controller.
   How to do that?

Comment: Couldn't you just make a segue between them on the storyboard, name it, and call `performSegueWithIdentifier`?

Comment: Actually, I did. I display every view controller, there is a segue between them.

Comment: A segue between D to A?

Comment: Yes you can do that, but the old one (A uiviewcontoller) is gonna be there forever till the app close. Am i right?

Comment: Can't you call `dismissViewController`?